# Restore Checkbox State from Dictionary

Tags: javascript, html

I am storing form data in json format.  To allow changing values from a previously created json file, the (plain old javascript) function below will load the values into a form from a file.  This method will restore the value of drop down lists but not with a checkbox.

I have tried storing the value of the checkbox ('on' or 'off') and the checked state ('true' or 'false') but neither works out of the box.

Also, I tried adding an if statement before the return, like so:

```
if (newArr[dataItem] === "true") {
  document.getElementById(newArr[dataItem]).click();
} else {
return (inputItem.id === dataItem) ? (inputItem.value = newArr[dataItem]) : false;
}
```

Here is a stripped down version of the function that works to restore values:

```
function receivedText(e) {
  let lines = e.target.result;
  var newArr = JSON.parse(lines);
  Object.keys(newArr).map(function (dataItem) {
    inputs.map(function (inputItem) {
      return (inputItem.id === dataItem) ? (inputItem.value = newArr[dataItem]) : false;
    });
  });
 }
```

The json data would look like this:

```
{ "foo": "ws", "bar": "ws", "checkbox_value": "on", "other_data": "apple" }
```

So in short, when loading data from a file and evaluating the json dictionary, the checkbox_value does not seem to select or deselect the checkbox.

Comment: `.map` returns a new Array, but you are not capturing that array in either of the two cases where you are using it.

Comment: why there is nowhere in the code something like: `inputCheckBox.checked = true / false`?

Comment: `checkbox` has default value `on` (usually omitted). Use `checked` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `checked` attribute, and it needs to be set to the booleans `true` and `false`, not the strings. You should store the `checked` attribute as a boolean in the JSON. To load the values, consider the following code:

```
Object.keys(newArr).map(function (dataItem) {
    var inputItem = document.getElementById(dataItem);
    if (inputItem.type === "checkbox") {
        inputItem.checked = newArr[dataItem];
    } else {
        inputItem.value = newArr[dataItem];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm!  It seemed like going with the booleans (true or false) would be the correct way.